# c# parsing and type conversion in a property getter/setter

Tags: c#, inheritance, getter-setter

I have been constantly revising my code on the best method for me to handle inheritance with a single table db structure using entity framework. By single table i mean there is a column for each property of the core object and all inherited properties are stored as a json object in a column called params. This object will represent the DB structure.

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public DateTime Created {get; set;}
    protected ExpandoObject Params {get; set;}
    public TypeEnum Type {get; set;}
}
```

I pull 1 parent from the DB and i do not know its type. I need to first parse it to a Parent object and then read the Type property to figure out what it is. From here i can cast it to its correct type. I have tried so many ways to handle this and i think i have come up with the cleanest possible way, but it results in having to put some parsing and data conversion in the getters. Here is an example.

```
public class Child : Parent
{
    public int ChildID{
        get {
            return Convert.ToInt32(this.Params.ChildID);
        }
        set {
            this.Params.ChildID = value;
        }
    }

    public SomeEnum SomeOtherType{
        get {
            return (SomeEnum)Convert.ToInt32(this.Params.SomeOtherType);
        }
        set {
            this.Params.SomeOtherType = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This to me is super clean as it hides the complexity of the implementation while also allowing me to easily cast Child to Parent without a loss of data. The issue i am seeing is that integers are being stored as a long and i need to convert them to be an int (it never needs to be a long). For enums it does the same. Is this kind of data handling acceptable to have in a getter of an object? The main drawback i see here is that the parse needs to be done every single time the property is called, but it isnt too expensive. If this is terrible practice, how should i be doing this?

The alternatives i have already considered are

1. Load/save properties using methods - I dont want to add order of execution to an already complex setup.
2. Table per type  - This wont work because it will double all of my DB queries as i do not know the object type on query time, therefore cannot query the type table to obtain that data at query time.
3. Completely new objects - cant do this as i need to keep the objects related so that entity can save an object of type Parent back to the DB

Comment: You have a trade-off between execution time and memory.  The difference between an integer and long is two bytes.  Some how many items do you have defined.  Is it worth the two extra bytes to do all the conversions between long and int.

Comment: @jdweng: the difference between long and integer is four bytes.

Comment: I guess i could change all of the data types to long, assuming it doesnt screw with how entity does its business and wont alter auto increment values (this is my only use of the data value). In the other side, the enum will still need to be parsed and i suspect other data types in the future may need casting. Still want to be 100% this sort of practice is acceptable

Comment: Although you claim the conversions are always safe, you do *appear* to have getters that could throw, which is usually a big no-no.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i agree. The alternative would have been having a load params and save params method. the load must be called after the object is loaded and save before sending it back to entity. That brings the headache of always making sure those methods are called.

Comment: Didn't have my morning cup of coffee.